# How could you rewrite a list of lists so that "islands" of values are unique from one another?

Tags: python

Let's say I've got a list of lists (or more conceptually accurate a 2D array):

```
list = [[1,1,0,0,0],
        [1,1,2,0,0],
        [0,2,2,2,0],
        [0,0,0,2,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0]]
```

I'd like to identify the different regions of identical values and rewrite the list so that each region has a unique value, like so:

```
list = [[1,1,2,2,2],
        [1,1,3,2,2],
        [0,3,3,3,2],
        [0,0,0,3,2],
        [0,0,0,4,2]]
```

I've mostly tried writing variations of a loop parsing the array per value and setting adjacent values equal to each other (which yea, is redundant I guess), BUT ensuring that island of 1s in the top left is distinct from the 1 in the bottom right was just not working. My attempts were spotty at best and non-functional at worst. Examples:

```
for x in list_length:
     for y in sublist_length:
          try:
               if list[x][y] == list[x+1][y]:
                    list[x+1][y] = list[x][y]
          except:
               pass
```

or

```
 predetermined_unique_value = 0

 for x in list_length:
     for y in sublist_length:
          try:
               if list[x][y] == list[x+1][y]:
                    list[x+1][y] = predetermined_unique_value
                    predetermined_unique_value += 1
          except:
               pass
```

and many slight variations on which directions (up, down, left, right from current spot/point) to check, brute forcing the loop by running it until all spots had been assigned a new value, etc.

Clearly I am missing something here. I suspect the answer is actually super simple, but I can't seem to find anything on google or reddit, or other answers here (I'm probably just conceptualizing it weirdly so searching for the wrong thing).

Just to reiterate, how could you parse that list of lists to organize values into adjacent regions based on identical data and rewrite it to ensure that those regions all have unique values? (I.E. so that there is only one region of the 0 value, one region of the 1 value, etc. etc.)

I hope this is enough information to help you help me, but in truth I just as much am not sure how to do this as I am doing it wrong. Please don't hesitate to ask for more.

Comment: The problem is that you try to modify the very same array you're iterating over. Just make a separate array that will store the island indices, and modify it instead.

Comment: Where did the `4` come from in the example output?

Comment: The input arrays has `{0: 15, 1: 5, 2: 5}` (ie, 15 `0`, 5 `1` and 5 `2`) but the output example has `{2: 8, 0: 7, 3: 5, 1: 4, 4: 1}` Please explain that transformation?

Comment: I think what he is trying to do is just find all clusters in that array, and then apply every cluster a unique number. The numbers in the original data aren't important or dont need to be compared with the output. Since his data contains 5 clusters, he uses the numbers 0 to 4. Am I right @Scoopz ?

Comment: @Alexey, yes--but how, I am very confused on how to do that? I am unsure of how to index the data in such a way that it will be able to differentiate between islands?

Comment: @dawg, it didnt--thats what im trying to achieve, nothing has produced that yet.

part 2, im not sure what you mean

Comment: @Rabinzel, yes this!

Comment: @Scoopz Did my answer help ? or do you want to go down your path and want to get some help on that

Comment: I suggest adding a spiral test case: `[[1,1,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847339/15521392) you can do it with `ndimage` from the `scipy` library.
I applied your data to his answer and that's what I got as result:

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

data_tup = ((1,1,0,0,0),
        (1,1,2,0,0),
        (0,2,2,2,0),
        (0,0,0,2,0),
        (0,0,0,1,0))

data_list = [[1,1,0,0,0],
        [1,1,2,0,0],
        [0,2,2,2,0],
        [0,0,0,2,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0]]

def find_clusters(array):
    clustered = np.empty_like(array)
    unique_vals = np.unique(array)
    cluster_count = 0
    for val in unique_vals:
        labelling, label_count = ndimage.label(array == val)
        for k in range(1, label_count + 1):
            clustered[labelling == k] = cluster_count
            cluster_count += 1
    return clustered, cluster_count

clusters, cluster_count = find_clusters(data_list)
clusters_tup, cluster_count_tup = find_clusters(data_tup)
print(" With list of lists, Found {} clusters:".format(cluster_count))
print(clusters, '\n')

print(" With tuples of tuple, Found {} clusters:".format(cluster_count_tup))
print(clusters_tup)

Output:

 With list of lists, Found 5 clusters:
[[2 2 0 0 0]
 [2 2 4 0 0]
 [1 4 4 4 0]
 [1 1 1 4 0]
 [1 1 1 3 0]] 

 With tuples of tuple, Found 5 clusters:
[[2 2 0 0 0]
 [2 2 4 0 0]
 [1 4 4 4 0]
 [1 1 1 4 0]
 [1 1 1 3 0]]
```

Both times the Output is a list of list. If you wish to have it different, the function needs to be changed inside.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer--would this work with an array of tuples?

Comment: I'd say yes, but lets just try and find out :)

Comment: haha I am, it would appear however that while it is returning new values its storing them inside a tuple instead of as an integer I.E. a tuple goes in as (for example) (99, 51, 120) and is coming out as (0 0 1) instead of 1. Maybe I should start a new question with the full script that this issue is apart of???

Comment: ah thank you, sorry I replied before I saw your answer

Comment: still need the new question or is it ok with the way it works now ? if not and there are other aspects, sure, start a new question with a link to this one

Comment: It's still outputting weird, I am going to start a new question with the full script and context. I'll link back here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71983997/18919905

Comment: this may shed more light on the situation

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`skimage.measure.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=measure#skimage.measure.label):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from skimage import measure
>>>
>>> a = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0],
        [1,1,2,0,0],
        [0,2,2,2,0],
        [0,0,0,2,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0]])
>>> measure.label(a, background=a.max()+1)
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 3, 2, 2],
       [4, 3, 3, 3, 2],
       [4, 4, 4, 3, 2],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 2]])
```

Note that the `label` function has an argument `connectivity` which determines how blobs/clusters are identified. The default for a 2D array is to consider diagonal neighbors. If that is undesired, `connectivity=1` will consider only horizontal/vertical neighbors.

Comment: Isn't the right import `from skimage import measure` as you use `measure.label` in the code ? other than that,nice way of solving it. I'm still figuring out why it works with defining the background like that :D

Comment: thanks very much for your answer! Like the other one, would this work with an array of tuples?

Comment: @Rabinzel Thanks for the hint. It works with the background definition because `a.max()+1` is guaranteed not to appear inside the array `a`. Hence, no element will be identified as background; instead all elements will be part of some blob/cluster. This is important, because all "background" element receive the same label `0`.

Comment: @Scoopz It only works with Numpy arrays, but that's not a big deal (if you install [`scikit-image`](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-image/) then [`numpy`](https://pypi.org/project/numpy) will be installed automatically as a dependency).

Comment: @a_guest nice, didn't think of that. Now I got it. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good the performance of this solution is but here's a recursive approach to identify a connected segment. It will take a coordinate and return the same list of islands with every coordinate that was part of the same island as the given coordinate with `True`.

```
islands = [[1,1,0,0,0],
        [1,1,2,0,0],
        [0,2,2,2,0],
        [0,0,0,2,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0]]

def print_islands():
        for row in islands:
                print(row)

def get_bool_map(i, j):
        checked_indexes = [[False] * len(islands[0]) ] * len(islands) 
        checked_cords = []
        def check_island_indexes(island_value, m, i, j):
                if i < 0 or j < 0:
                        return
                try:
                        if m[i][j] != island_value:
                                return
                        else:
                                if [i, j] in checked_cords:
                                        return
                                else:
                                        checked_cords.append([i, j])
                                m[i][j] = True
                except IndexError:
                        return
                check_island_indexes(island_value, m, i - 1, j)
                check_island_indexes(island_value, m, i + 1, j)
                check_island_indexes(island_value, m, i, j - 1)
                check_island_indexes(island_value, m, i, j + 1)
        check_island_indexes(islands[i][j], islands, i, j)

get_bool_map(0, 4)
print_islands()

[1, 1, True, True, True]
[1, 1, 2, True, True]
[0, 2, 2, 2, True]
[0, 0, 0, 2, True]
[0, 0, 0, 1, True]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).