# Replace int values in 2D np.array with list of 3 values to make it 3D

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I came along this problem when helping on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983997/reading-pngs-how-do-you-identify-clusters-of-color-and-rewrite-the-image-file) where OP does some image processing. Regardless if there are other ways to do the whole thing, in one part, I have a `2D np.array` filles with integers. The integers are just mask values, each standing for a RGB color.

I have a dictionary with integers as keys and arrays of RGB colors as value. This is the mapping and the goal is to replace each int in the array with the colors.

Starting with this array where all RGB-array where already replaced by integers so now it is an array of shape (2,3) (originially it was shape(2,3,3))

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0,2,4,1,3,5]).reshape(2,3)
print(arr)

array([[0, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 5]])
```

Here is the dictionary (chosen numbers are just random for the example):

```
dic = {0 : [10,20,30], 1 : [12,22,32], 2 : [15,25,35], 3 : [40,50,60], 4 : [100,200,300], 5 : [250,350,450]}
```

replacing all these values with the arrays makes it an array with shape (2,3,3) like this:

```
array([[[ 10,  20,  30],
        [ 15,  25,  35],
        [100, 200, 300]],
        
       [[ 12,  22,  32],
        [ 40,  50,  60],
        [250, 350, 450]]])
```

I looked into `np.where` because I thought it is the most obvious to me but I always got the error that the shapes are incorrect.
I don't know where exactly I'm stuck, when googling, I came across `np.dstack`, `np.concatenate`, reading about changing the shape with `np.newaxis / None` but I just don't get it done. Maybe creating a new array with `np.zeros_like` and go from there.
Do I need to create something like a placeholder before I'm able to insert an array holding these 3 RGB values?

Since every single key is in the array because it is created based on that, I thought about loop through the dict, check for key in array and replace it with the dict.value. Am I at least in the right direction or does that lead to nothing?

Any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: there were written two comments and then removed, under my answer. If sorting is matter in dictionary, it is easy to do. For improving the answer please modify your example as you need. Again, just sorting, is an easy work.

Comment: I just tested it. Thanks! It seems to work in my special case where each value in the arr is also in the dic. I removed one key in the dict and run it again, than I got an error that `index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 and size 5` . So in general I guess there needs to be another way. The sorting matter was removed because I guess he noticed it isn't relevant here.

Comment: What would be happened if you remove a key??? When `arr.size` is not compatible with dictionary size? Could you write another example that shows what you need exactly? What is the expected result if the one key be removed?

Comment: All good, I'm happy with this. Your answer solves my specific case. I just said, in general. If the array is way bigger and has values that are not in the dictionary, than this way will cause an error (which I just tested). Assuming that with the help of the dict only a part of the whole arr gets changed, like 50% of the values gets replaced and the other 50% just stay like they were before

Comment: @Ali_Sh forget what I just said. Doesn't make sense. If I want to replace a single value with a list of values, it needs to be done on every single value otherwise the shape inside the array isn't correct. I'll accpet your answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this regard, we can create an array of dictionary values by unpacking that and then order them based on the specified orders in the `arr`. So:

```
np.array([*dic.values()])[arr]
```

If the dictionary keys were not in a sorted order, we can create a mask array for ordering based on them, using `np.argsort`. So, after sorting the array of dictionary values based on the mask array, we can get the results again e.g.:

```
dic = {0: [10, 20, 30], 2: [15, 25, 35], 3: [40, 50, 60], 1: [12, 22, 32], 4: [100, 200, 300], 5: [250, 350, 450]}


sort_mask = np.array([*dic.keys()]).argsort()
# [0 3 1 2 4 5]

np.array([*dic.values()])[sort_mask][arr]
# [[[ 10  20  30]
#   [ 15  25  35]
#   [100 200 300]]
# 
#  [[ 12  22  32]
#   [ 40  50  60]
#   [250 350 450]]]
```

Comment: hmm correct me if I'm wrong, but sorting is really absolutely no issue here, otherwise my question would be just nonsene or am I wrong ? The whole idea is to go through the array of values, search for that value in the dict (wherever and at whatever position that key appears) and replace the arr-integer with de dict-array ..... I wasn't the one who wrote that is has to be sorted. just wanted to point that out :)